# Not Able To Play Flash Video in Android WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I am trying to show this [URL](http://api.virool.com/offers/wall/53dfddc7655ed1ca32e617cf80f7484c?suid=2) in webview. When I run this in my device it i am getting list of flash videos.when i click on any video i am getting below error.

[image]

I have downloaded several flash players from Google Play but always getting same result.
I am testing this on Samsung tab and my project version is 4.0.

It also giving same result in another all devices.

Here is my [activity class](http://pastie.org/4778831)

& here is my [manifest file](http://pastie.org/4778832)

What other attempt do I need to do?

Answer (score 4):

Add this to the tag under your Applications Manifest XML inside

> activity

tag and reload

> android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Comment: Thanks for the upvote , this is my first one since joining SO couple days ago . Historic moment for me.